# how to get RIOT.dll

Tags: c#, dll

I'm trying now for 5hours to get riot.dll (so that I can use it in my c# application). I have downloaded riot standalone application from  http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/download/ 
and RIOT as plug-in for other applications. I can't find dll. It's not in any folder after instalation. I downloaded zip file (download RIOT DLL version) http://download.criosweb.ro/download.php?sid=R-dll which contains .exe. Again after instaling that .exe I can't find .dll nowhere.

I know that it's probably some stupid solution but I just can't see it now.

Comment: Out of interest have you posted on their forums?

Comment: yes I did. Before posting here.

Comment: I posted there once more. Maybe I get faster response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received response on official site. Riot.dll can be found here

http://luci.criosweb.ro/download/Riot_dll_noinstall.zip